# Data retrieval failed for RDLC subreport

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I am running an RDLC Report with a click "Print Preview' button opens a PDF, but data in the subReport is missing, its telling "data retrieval failed for the subreport located at ..."

But the data is coming properly from the database .Could you please help out on this?

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We are trying to implement subreportprocessing event but when we have created the object of LocalReport ,we are not getting the SubreportProcessing event via the object ,can u please help out on this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using shared dataset or embedded dataset ? 
This issue occurs only on Business Integrated Development Studio (BIDS) and use a shared dataset in subreport.
So you can avoid this issue by changing the **shared dataset** to **embedded dataset** .
Hope this helps you .

Comment: I am not using SSRS Report ,I am using RDLC Report ,is there any shared dataset in RDLC

Comment: We  are  trying  to implement subreportprocessing event  but when we have created the object of LocalReport ,we are not getting the SubreportProcessing event via the object ,can u please help out on this.

Comment: Refer this [link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx)  and [link2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/01/02/walkthrough-add-a-subreport-in-local-report-in-reportviewer/)

Comment: This may help you @ArijitDan